# Howto unzip ".xz" file with 7z and lzma

Tags: linux, unix, zip, archiving, 7-zip

I tried to uncompressed a "*.xz" file with both **7z** and **lzma**. 
But they gave me such message:

```
$ 7z x myfile.fq.xz 

7-Zip 4.57  Copyright (c) 1999-2007 Igor Pavlov  2007-12-06
p7zip Version 4.57 (locale=C,Utf16=off,HugeFiles=on,4 CPUs)

Processing archive: myfile.fq.xz

Error: Can not open file as archive

$ 7z x myfile.fq.xz 

7-Zip 4.57  Copyright (c) 1999-2007 Igor Pavlov  2007-12-06
p7zip Version 4.57 (locale=C,Utf16=off,HugeFiles=on,4 CPUs)

Processing archive: myfile.fq.xz

Error: Can not open file as archive
```

and with **lzma**

```
$ lzma -d myfile.fq.xz  
J_12.fq.xz:  unknown suffix -- unchanged
```

with other option:

```
 $ lzma -S .xz -d myfile.fq.xz  
lzma: SetDecoderProperties() error
```

Comment: And `file` says...?

Comment: @Ignacio: Sorry I don't get you.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/1/file

Comment: @Ignacio: It gave me this:"$ file myfile.fq.xz -> myfile.fq.xz:data"

Comment: For (reluctant) Windows users, the [git-bash](https://git-scm.com/download/win) shell includes unxz.exe

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried downloading the XZ Utils from http://tukaani.org/xz/ ?

The XZ documentation says:

> At least the following software support the .xz file format:
>
> - XZ Utils
> - XZ Embedded
> - 7-Zip and LZMA SDK versions 9.00 alpha and later

I don't know if the 9.00 alpha version can be compared to your 4.57 version, but if it can, then maybe you simply just need to upgrade 7-zip.

Answer (score 6):

To add to `snowlord`'s notes,

Extract from the [7-zip version history](http://www.7-zip.org/history.txt),

```
9.04 beta      2009-05-30
-------------------------
- supports LZMA2 compression method.
- supports XZ archives.
- can unpack NTFS, FAT, VHD and MBR archives.
- can unpack GZip, BZip2, LZMA, XZ and TAR archives from stdin.
```

and, version `4.65` released `2009-02-03` is the last version number in 4.xx series.

Regarding the [version numbering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip#Version_numbering_scheme_change),

> After version 4.65, 7-Zip switched to a "Year.Revision" version numbering scheme, similar to the one used by Ubuntu and some other projects. The first release under the new scheme was 9.07 beta.

So, an [upgrade](http://www.7-zip.org/) should help.
Try the `Beta` version -- which is `9.13` at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

If you are running Ubuntu, you should have the *xz-utils* installed by default. I am running Ubuntu 10.04, and to extract .xz files, I use the following command:

```
xz -d path/to/file.xz
```

This will extract the file to the current directory.